# Has Mexico (+52) stopped using the 01/02/044/045 phone number dialing codes?

Tags: mexico, telephone

The Wiki page for Mexican phone numbers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Mexico

and the translation of this site linked from it: https://www.ift.org.mx/comunicacion-y-medios/comunicados-ift/es/el-pleno-del-ift-aprobo-los-indices-y-parametros-de-calidad-del-servicio-movil-y-aprobo-los-nuevos

both suggest that Mexico has finally stopped using the complex set of national/international dialing codes (e.g. 044/045 for mobile numbers, 01/02 for fixed line etc.).

Since these sort of deadlines will slip, often by months or years, can someone with first hand knowledge of the current situation in Mexico say what the situation is (and ideally point at a news article or similar evidence that the migration is truly complete and whether the old numbers are still usable today)?

Btw, I'm very aware of `Libphonenumber` and what it does, but all its sources are very out of date, so it doesn't help here.